# "Error 5: Access denied" when installing programs with UAC turned off

Tags: windows-7, installation, uac

I'm having some trouble installing msysgit 1.7.3.1preview on Windows 7 Home Premium. I downloaded the setup file from the Google Code and then ran it. Upon running, I got the following error:

[image]

I have tried downloading and running different older versions of msysgit with no luck. For the record, I have administrative privileges and there are no other user accounts on this Windows machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I have managed to semi-fix this problem. I turned on User Account Control back to the default setting and and then ran the setup file as an administrator. I successfully managed to install Git. However, this means I have to keep UAC turned on whenever I want to install a new program (I realised that it persists over all programs; not just Git). So it's quite a nuisance.

If anybody knows how I could keep UAC disabled whilst still being able to install programs without running their setup files as an administrator, I would be eternally grateful.

**UPDATE:** *I have changed the question title to better suit the new situation.*

Comment: Try running as admin -> `right click setup.exe` -> `Run As Admin`.

Comment: Tried doing that, but still no love.

Comment: When the error message pops up can you see who the installer is running as using process explorer? If the setup.exe is loader for something like MSI the actual running user might be someone different, like LocalSystem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permissions issue, not a UAC issue.  There shouldn't be any permissions problems when creating a file/folder in your own user profile.  Can you manually create a file/folder in that path without it requiring elevated access?  If not you have ACL issues as mentioned in another comment.

Comment: *> Looks like a permissions issue, not a UAC issue.*   That is what I thought as well, but I strongly suspect that *is* [his](http://superuser.com/users/58582/aero) own user profile, so it *shouldn't* be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an UAC issue as seen [in this other setup trouble](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7security/thread/37f9beec-5129-48ee-8860-71d705ff16af#c1ad0edc-5d32-49d5-bab0-f9d4c6216562) (not related to msysgit)

See [this post](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7security/thread/55dce284-0dcd-46af-892e-d2b9cf5bcff6#6de0b677-d485-4c91-800e-9d881543943a)

> It can be a issue in the UAC File Virtualization Filter Driver, therefore make sure you’re user account has permission to be able to run applications that need to write to the `AppData -> %TEMP%` directory.

[image]

---

If UAC is turned off, and if running the install as Admin changes nothing (because you already are admin), [you can also try](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=01b8cb8c0b4f56d4&hl=en):

> 1. Create a folder name "`Temp`" under `C:\`   // This step is important, the folder has
>      to exist.
> 2. Right click the Computer in `Start` menu and select `Properties`
> 3. Click `Advanced System Setting`
> 4. In `System Properties` windows, click `Advanced` tab
> 5. Click `Environment Variables` button
> 6. Under `User variables` list, double click `TMP`
> 7. Change Variable value: from "`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`" to "`C:\Temp`"

Comment: Not sure what I'm supposed to do here... I have UAC turned off.

Comment: @Aero: did you try to change the TMP variable? I have updated my answer with a link and a process for that.

Comment: I've followed the steps, and now I get the same error except the path is C:\Temp and not the previous path. I do appreciate your help, though. I've also only recently upgraded (not a clean install) from Vista to 7 so that may be an issue.

Comment: @Aero: interesting. There is obviously some ACL issue with this migration...

Comment: I've managed to partly solve the problem - added details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Some installers seem to be able to install. For others (e.g. Git) it looks like you have to "run as Administrator" but you do may leave UAC turned off. (Tested with Windows 10)